# Using Actionscript (MovieClip) class in flex

Tags: apache-flex, movieclip

I have a piece of Actionscript code that Implements MovieClip. I don't seem to be able to get it to display in my application.

What I've tried:
1) Using the class directly in my code via UIObject and Sprite. I can create the UIObject, add the Sprite and then add an instance of the class. Nothing displays in my app.

2) Putting the class in as a flex library (swc). The compiler won't let me import it or use it as a display object.

3) Putting the class in as a flex project (swf). The file runs fine stand alone but gives me the same "broken" icon when I try to use it in my app.

Im missing some key factor here. Suggestions?

EDIT: Got the add-in class to display via a library. It compiles to a .SWC file. Unfortunately it's using the full screen as its 'stage' dimensions. The issue I was having before with it not being visible was actually (or so I think) that it was off the right side of the display window. I put break points in the drawing routines and could see that it was being refreshed. So now Im trying to get it to accept some dimensions.

Comment: +1 for telling us what you tried.

Comment: Im hoping to implement some form of the 'cumulus tag cloud'. It was written as a WP add-in but its open sourced so maybe I can adapt it.

Comment: It all works like it should. Its your code that is wrong. Try it in asimple test and work from there. Post any code you stumble on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a UIComponent instead of UIObject and add the movieclip to the UIComponent. I have always used UIComponent instead of UIObject and my sprite is always displayed correctly :) mxml and code below:

```
<mx:UIComponent>
    <mx:Yoursprite></mx:Yoursprite>
</mx:UIComponent>
```

or coded in actionscript:

```
private function createSpriteInFlex():void
{
    var _uiComponent:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    addElement(_uiComponent);

    var _sprite:YourSprite = new YourSprite();
    _uiComponent.addChild(_sprite);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can just add an mxml line like this.

```
<com:myUIComponent width="100%" height="100%"></com:myUIComponent>
```

So the myUIComponent is actually a class that you can code yourself. I will demonstrate how you can add a sprite or movieclip below:

```
package com.myUIComponent
{
    public class myUIComponent extends UIComponent
    {
        public function myUIComponent()
        {
            super();

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            //ADD YOUR SPRITE HERE
            var mySprite:YourSprite = new YourSprite();
            addChild(mySprite);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this as part of using the class locally. Added a UIComponent to my page, then added the Sprite and finally the MovieClip. Appeared to go in ok but nothing displayed.

Comment: I had assumed--perhaps incorrectly that his reference to UIObject was a typo for UIComponent; based on a quick search, UIObject was part of Flex 1.5; but no links show up for Flex 2 or greater.

Comment: Normally, this should work. Have you tried the coded approach or the mxml-approach? I will update my post with another (coded) example.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Using the class directly in my code
>   via UIObject and Sprite. I can create
>   the UIObject, add the Sprite and then
>   add an instance of the class. Nothing
>   displays in my app.

Did you give the move clip and size?  ( Width and height) and position (x and y)?  The size is usually more important because x and y are often set to 0, 0.

```
2) Putting the class in as a flex library (swc). The compiler won't let me import it or use it as a display object.
```

did you add the SWC to your library path?  Are you sure your new movie clip is included in the SWC?

```
3) Putting the class in as a flex project (swf). The file runs fine stand alone but gives me the same "broken" icon when I try to use it in my app.
```

It sounds like you have a path issue w/ embedding here; but you'd have to show your code.

Comment: MovieClip has size and position. When added from an external file (be it SWF or SWC) I see it positioned but it won't draw.

Comment: @ethrbunny Please show your code for "adding it".  Are you embedding it?  Or using a SWFLoader? Or something else?